# Using grep -P and lookahead/lookbehind to get text between patterns

Tags: regex, grep

Assume the following is in `file.txt`:

```
---------
foo bar
more foo bar
---------
```

when I execute `grep -P '(?<=-$)(?s:.)*(?=^-)' file.txt`, I expect only the middle two lines to be matched, but this expression matches nothing. What's wrong?
I also tried `grep -P '(?s)(?<=-$).*(?=^-)' file.txt` but same result.

Comment: Try `grep -Poz '(?s)-\R\K.*(?=\R-)' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Tried it. Same result (no matches) :(

Comment: `grep -v '^-*$'` to print any lines that aren't all `-`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/EDLhKK, it works.

Comment: @Barmar Nice solution, thanks. But I mainly want to understand **why** the solution I mentioned is not working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. It works! Could you please explain what do \R and \K mean? Also do you know what's wrong with the solution I had before?

Comment: To make anchors match start and end of lines you'd need `m` flag, and you need `zo` options, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You mean something like `grep -Poz '(?ms)(?<=-$).*(?=^-)' file.txt`, right? This worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern dos not work because

- The `P` option alone only makes `grep` match using the PCRE regex engine
- Since you have no other options, `grep` outputs whole matched lines, you need to add `o` option to output the matched text(s) and `z` to slurp the file into a single text
- Your regex has `^` and `$` anchors that match start/end of the *string*, not lines, by default. You need a `m` flag together with `s` flag (it makes `.` match any char including line break chars).

So, you may use your regex with `m` and `-oz`:

```
grep -Poz '(?ms)(?<=-$).*(?=^-)' file.txt
```

Or,

```
grep -Poz '(?s)-\R\K.*(?=\R-)' file.txt
```

where `\R` matces any line break sequence and `\K` omits the text matched so far from the overall memory buffer.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BxB6WO/2).